# Unhandled exception in C# application does it crash the app?

Tags: c#

In my C# application when I run it in debug mode in Visual Studio, it breaks saying I have an unhandled exception (it is a System.ArgumentException). But when I run it in release mode, the application does not crash.

My question is what is the consequence if I have unhandled exception? Does ithe application crash when user runs into the scenario?

Comment: of course it crashes

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Is it a console app? If yes, try running it outside the ide.

Comment: Why don't you try it? It takes me 10 minutes to write a Proof of Concept.

Comment: Are you sure it's saying it's unhandled, or is Visual Studio just breaking execution upon an exception _being thrown_, even though it's then handled?

Comment: *Breaking in the debugger* isn't the same thing as *crashing*. The debugger will break whenever you tell it to. That doesn't mean that the exception is unhandled. What happens with unhandled exceptions though depends on the application type. Typically, the application will crash

Comment: Consider adding related peace of code or preparing [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unhandled exception in C# application does it crash the app?

If you mean 'unhandled' in a sense 'unhandled by me' then it's not necessarily. Lets say that your method starts from static void Main (in main thread) and it throws exception that is not handled. This should crash your application. But on the other hand if you run the same method asynchronously in a new Task(Method) it'll crash the Thread where this Task is executed yes, but not your application (this exception will be handled automatically by the Task Manager).

P.S. 
So *any exception that is unhandled terminates program flow.*

Comment: How about [`ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj160346.aspx) ?

Comment: If an exception does not crash/terminate the process then it has been handled. Perhaps not by your code but then by an exception handler in the framework. This also applies to tasks where you can configure if "unobserved task exceptions" should be handled or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is really unhandled (it bubbles through all layers) than it´ll result in a crash of your app. However as others already mentioned before when the exception is just thrown on some line of code and catched an any other decent point VS may show the error and afterwards will continue debugging within your catch-handler.

Consider this code:

```
void Main(string[] args) 
{
    try {
        DoSomething();
    } catch {
        /* error-handling happens here */
    }
}

void DoSomething {
    // this exception will bubble until Main and is handled there --> no crash
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

However if you do not have any `try-catch`-block within your `Main`-method (or within `DoSomething`) the application will also bubble through but hence it is not handled it will lead to app-crash.

Comment: Regarding *may show the error*, i prefer to detect myself when app is running with debugger attached and do not handle unhandled exceptions in this case, this way they are guaranteed to crash and are easier to debug.